# AngularJS data binding input vs non-input elements

Tags: angularjs

What is the difference in AngularJS data-binding when binding a `model to an input` vs binding a `model with a non-input` element (e.g. div)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non input type elements are intended to use ng-bind which provides one way binding but input types use ng-model to provide 2 way binding.

If you want 2 way binding on a non input but editable (html5) element you will have to implement that yourself for such elements to support ng-model.

example of adding support for ng-model to non input element is:

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      function read() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
      }

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
      };

      element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
        scope.$apply(read);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

source: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html

And finally let's not forget the third option angular offers which is a "One time" or one off binding. which happens only once if you don't need the binded element to keep updating after it's first initial value from the scope:

```
<p>Hello {{::name}}!</p>

<custom-directive two-way-attribute="::oneWayExpression"></custom-directive>
```

Source: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Comment: You're very welcome. Please accept the answer if this was useful to you.

Comment: Absolutely, I forgot it while waiting for 3 min restriction in accepting the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Angular has special directive which enables two way data binding for input elements `ng-model`, then it has also two way but in practice it behaves as one way binding `ng-bind` or shorthand `{{expresion}}`, then again it has a proper one time binding using `{{::expresion}}` when you are sure you only want  to display initial data which will not be updated by any other proces later. So if you want to mutate your model using inputs go for `ng-model`.

Comment: :: is NOT one way binding. It is one time binding

Comment: Thank you for pointing out mistake, ofcourse you are right and :: is one time binding which is evaluated only  once and will not reflect data changes into template